# DeleteVertexShader dx8.1 to dx9 conversion

Tags: directx, directx-9

i am currently trying to convert a game to use dx9 instead of dx8. I would say that i'm quite close to completing it, but I have a few errors that I don't exactly know how to deal with atm.

1. `DeleteVertexShader` and `DeletePixelShader` do not exist anymore in directx 9. What do I do with those? I could not find any equivalent to them in dx9 so far.
   Old code example:

`D3D_CHECKERROR(hr); hr = _pGfx->gl_pd3dDevice->DeletePixelShader(ulHandle);`

2. Render state `D3DRS_PATCHSEGMENTS` does not exist anymore, it was used for the number of segments per edge when drawing patches. Do I need to replace it with something? I could not find any equivalent for this either.
   Code example:

   `HRESULT hr = _pGfx->gl_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_PATCHSEGMENTS, *((DWORD*)&fSegments));`

These two issues are the ones I have the most struggles with atm, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. In Direct3D 9, vertex shader and pixel shaders return COM interfaces to the shader object. Therefore, it's deleted whenever the IUnknown reference count is 0. See [Microsoft Docs: Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).
2. The 'n-patch' and 'rect/tri-patch' features were never widely supported or used. Direct3D 9 does support these legacy features [Using Higher-Order Primitives (Direct3D 9)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/using-higher-order-primitives), but only if the hardware reports support via `D3DDEVCAPS_NPATCHES` / `D3DDEVCAPS_RTPATCHES`.

> You can also take a look at some of the n-patch support in legacy D3DX9, but you probably just need to rewrite this code for modern cards.

See [Microsoft Docs: Converting to Direct3D 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/converting-to-directx-9).

> Be sure to read [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) as well.